# How to SVN Commit all files, except one, using command-line only?

Tags: svn, command-line

In my project, there are 25 modified files. I need to commit 24 of those files to the SVN Repository. The one single file that I do not want to commit is not complete yet, so I will commit it at a later date.

I'm using a remote shell on a Linux Server to do SVN commits. The only way I know how to do the above is to type:

```
# svn ci file1 file2 file3 file4........... file24
```

It's kind of ridiculous and inefficient. Is there an easier alternative to this? Can I *commit everything* but choose to leave out certain files?

Is some fancy bash script needed for this?

Comment: hm, the only idea that i have is. Temporarily ignore the file you don't want to commit, commit everything else, and remove the ignore afterwards. But i think ignore doesn't work that way, if the file is already in the repository ...

Comment: I thought about that as well but it seems like it's a silly way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it in a single transaction try something like this:

```
svn commit `svn status | sed -n -e '/file_you_dont_want/!s/^.......//p'`
```

Comment: The inability to do simple things like this reminds me why so many folks are migrating away from Subversion

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You could write a bash script that commits all the files in a certain directory, except those that you pass it as an argument.  The core of the script is a loop:

```
for x in `ls`
do
     svn ci $x
done
```

You can either choose to put together a filter by piping the output of ls through grep, or put an if statement inside the loop.  I'd probably go for the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use changelist:

```
svn cl _listName_ -R *
svn --remove unexpected_filenames
svn commit --cl _listName_
```